# matplotlib doesn't plot all values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm working in a Jupyter notebook and I'm trying to plot [this Pickled dataframe](https://fil.email/YIsXEPpw)

```
index       value
------------------
2020-10-19  3
2020-10-26  4
2020-11-02  3
2020-11-09  2
2020-11-16  1
2020-11-23  3
2020-11-30  1
2020-12-07  4
2020-12-14  6
2020-12-21  3
2020-12-28  1
2021-01-04  1
2021-01-11  5
2021-01-18  10
2021-01-25  9
2021-02-01  8
2021-02-08  12
2021-02-15  6
```

I am using this code (divided in different cells, but irrelevant to say):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.style.use('ggplot')

data = pd.read_pickle('data.pkl')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

weekly = data.resample('W-MON').sum()
ax.plot(weekly)

labels = [f"{d.day}-{d.month}-{d.year}" for d in weekly.index]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
```

It produces this plot, but **it's missing the latter half of the data**:

[image]

Comment: I don't think the values are missing. It seems like your graph doesn't match the data provided. The problem might come from your labels.

Comment: @Jao even if I comment that line, the labels look ugly but they are still the same and same amount

Comment: What I mean is that the data seems to be plotted correctly. The problem is not the data it's the labels that don't match them.

Comment: @Jao I have checked, in fact they don't match. that's because the ticks are half the length of the data. I need all the ticks to match the index of my data. I can't figure out how

Comment: It is almost certainly because of `weekly`doesn't match your data. You used `resampling`and from what I have read it will here merge data by week. So you have a maximum of one label per week. Because some of your labels were merged togethers some are missing. You should either not resample your labels or check what is plotted by `ax.plot(weekly) it is not the aggregated data.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was that the ticks amount were automatically generated by the plot, thus being half the amount I needed. It was sufficient to specify how many via `ax.set_xticks()`

```py
ax.set_xticks(weekly.index)  # <--
labels = [f"{d.day}-{d.month}-{d.year}" for d in weekly.index]
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, rotation=45)
```

Sometimes the smaller problems are those that cause more confusion, but oh well...